# How to get input tag value given in browser without using form using beautifulsoup python web scrape

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to get user input value from the browser where the input tag is not a part of the form tag, it is just a plan input tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="vacation">
        <label for="fromooo" id="fromtime">From time</label>
        <input type="text" id="fromvalue" value/>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="toooo" id="totime">TO time</label>
        <input type="text" id="tovalue" value/>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my python scraper code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('index.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file,'lxml')


match = soup.find('input',id='fromvalue')
print(match.value)
```

When I run the above script I am getting as NONE

NOTE: the value for input is given by the user in the browser.
Required output: 3454 (user has typed 3454 in browser).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are accessing a **index.html** which is not being updated on user input.

Comment: Thank you , got where I was making a mistake